# nginx service repeatedly, stopped working after a random certain time

Tags: server, apache2, nginx, webserver

Please assist me to solve this error permanently. I don't know why it occurs again and again.

[image]

After command's `sudo service httpd stop` and then `sudo service nginx start` it's solved for few day's such as from 2-4 day. However again this error occurred after mentioned time.
[Here is my nginx.conf file](https://gitlab.com/haideryaqoobengr/haiderconf.git)

Comment: First of all, `httpd` is for the apache server and so `httpd` and `nginx` are different services. Secondly, I would like to see the logs for when it stops.

Comment: @ystark Thank You for your response. Yes, you are right. However, when i disable httpd. It is giving me this error after certain time "Access to XMLHttpRequest at "subdomain which is pointing to backend node server" from "domain" has been blocked by cors policy: Response to preflight request  doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *' but only one is allowed.

Comment: @ystark and this error is solved by again enabling httpd. secondly, right now i can't share logs because right now it's working, i can after certain time when it will again start giving error, which i can solve with command's mentioned in question.